# SQL Query: Insert name, get other names with same value

Tags: sql

Insert name into parameter window and get a list of names with the same value.

Example: insert "John" = John, Kim, Carl

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| Kim | 1 |
| Carl | 1 |
| Will | 2 |
| Martin | 2 |
| Diana | 3 |
| Anna | 3 |

Comment: Could you please clarify in your post what you are asking?

Comment: If Gordon's post answered your question, you should accept it. Click the check-mark and consider upvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select t.name
from t
where t.value in (select t2.value from t t2 where t2.name = 'John');
```

Comment: In the example data, there are two name=John rows, so `IN` might be better than the equal (but I'm not sure the example data matches the expected results anyway).

Comment: @EdmCoff . . . That is a really good point.  The OP didn't seem to notice that either.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query, It works with self-join.

```
select Name from table as org 
inner join table as val 
on org.Value=val.Value 
where val.Name= 'John'
```